# Efficient text-wrapping for variable window sizes in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a program that outputs a large amount of scrollable text. I wanted the text to wrap automatically based on the window size, and was able to do so by configuring and event function that adjusted it automatically. Originally, the user needed to click a button to switch pages to display the results, something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
class textwrap(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        self.page = 0
        self.results = []
        self.go = tk.Button(self, text = "Go", command = self.run)
        self.go.grid()
        self.swap_button = tk.Button(self, text = "Change page", command = self.swap)
        self.swap_button.grid()

    def run(self):
        for x in range(1000):
            self.results.append('abcdefg abcdefg')
    def swap(self):
        if self.page == 0:
            self.go.destroy()
            self.page = 1
            self.results_label = tk.Label(self, text = self.results, wraplength = self.master.winfo_width())
            self.results_label.grid()
        else:
            self.results_label.destroy()
            self.page = 0
            self.go = tk.Button(self, text = "Go", command = self.run)
            self.go.grid(row = 0)
    
frame01 = textwrap()
frame01.mainloop()
```

I have excluded the auto-wrapping and scrollbar here. The problem with this model, as quickly becomes apparent, is that putting in too much text will eventually cause the program to freeze up when trying to display the data. I tried to find a workaround using a ScrolledText box (Text field with scrollbar built in), storing it in a second tab in a ttk notebook, and writing to it in real time like so:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
class textwrap2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        self.text_field = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(state = 'disabled')
        self.text_field.grid()
        self.go = tk.Button(self, text = "Go", command = self.run)
        self.go.grid()

    def run(self):
        self.text_field.config(state='normal')
        for x in range(1000):
            self.text_field.insert(tk.END, x)
        self.text_field.config(state='disabled')
    
frame01 = textwrap2()
frame01.mainloop()
```

While this lacks the initial lag on open, the entire program begins to slow after a large amount of data is added, and the scrollbar lags terribly, even worse than with an equivalent amount of data that successfully loaded in the previous version.

**What I am asking is effectively this: Is there any efficient way to create wrapped text of a large size, with a scrollbar?** Trying to load an extremely large list all at once freezes the program, and loading it in real time as it is created causes the program as a whole to slow down the larger it gets. I considered loading it in real time with myriad labels created iteratively, but wasn't sure how to wrap them as a collective. Another question about scrollbar lag suggested inserting newline characters automatically after a certain distance, rather than using automatic wrapping. The problem is that if the window is ever resized, the wrapping will no longer be accurate, and there is no easy way to  fix it after that point. The simple Notepad app on Windows makes child's play of this issue, so I was wondering if there was an obvious solution that was evading me.

Comment: how large is this text?

Comment: maybe you will have to change framework - ie. PyQt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround was successful (though it introduced new problems in my original program, but that's beyond the scope of this question). Scrolling with labels was much smoother than with the text field, so I went back to that. Loading an excessively large label all at once caused problems, so I avoided this by automatically breaking the input into separate labels of a certain size. While this does cause imperfect line breaks in those places, the labels sizes are large enough that this doesn't cause much of an issue overall. The code would be something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
class textwrap3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack()
        self.master.geometry("1280x720")
        self.master.update_idletasks() 
        self.inputs_list = []
        self.starting_thousand = 0
        self.ending_thousand = 7000
        
#Creates the canvas with frame to hold data, and vertical scrollbar.
#This part isn't the solution, but is required to visualize how the solution works.
        self.results_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width = self.master.winfo_width()-20, height = self.master.winfo_height()-30)
        self.results_canvas.grid(sticky='new')
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient = 'vertical', command = self.results_canvas.yview)
        self.results_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.results_frame = tk.Frame(self.results_canvas)
        self.results_canvas.create_window((0,0), window = self.results_frame, anchor = 'n')
        self.results_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.results_canvas.configure
                               (scrollregion = self.results_canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.scroll.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'nse')
        self.current_thousand_label = tk.Label(self.results_frame, wraplength = self.master.winfo_width()-20)
        self.current_thousand_label.grid()

        self.go = tk.Button(self, text = "Go", command = self.run)
        self.go.grid()
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.wrap)
#Automaticlly wraps the text
    def wrap(self, event):
        self.results_canvas.config(width = self.master.winfo_width()-20, height = self.master.winfo_height() - 30)
        self.results_frame.config(width = self.master.winfo_width()-20)
        for widget in self.results_frame.winfo_children():
                widget.config(wraplength=self.master.winfo_width()-20)

    def run(self):
        for x in range(99700,100300):
            self.inputs_list.append(x)
        self.thousand_wrap()
        self.current_thousand_label.config(text = self.inputs_list[self.starting_thousand:])
#The workaround itself
    def thousand_wrap(self):
        if len(self.inputs_list) >= self.ending_thousand:
            self.current_thousand_label.destroy()
            self.previous_thousand_labels = tk.Label(self.results_frame,
                            text = self.inputs_list[self.starting_thousand:self.ending_thousand],
                            wraplength = self.master.winfo_width()-20)
            self.previous_thousand_labels.grid()
            self.starting_thousand += 7000
            self.ending_thousand += 7000
            self.current_thousand_label = tk.Label(self.results_frame, wraplength = self.master.winfo_width()-20)
            self.current_thousand_label.grid()
         
frame01 = textwrap3()
frame01.mainloop()
```

After reaching a certain number of large labels, the text will get cut off. I think it is related to the inherent size limitations of tkinter canvases, but that is beyond the scope of my original question, and I believe this proof-of-concept shows how large amounts of data can be displayed at least without massive program lag. You can change `self.ending_thousand` and the additions to starting and ending thousand under `thousand_wrap()` to alter the size of each label.

Answer (score 1):

The text widget doesn't perform well when lines of text are very long. From a paper written very early in the life of the tk toolkit (written around 1996):

> Alas, very long lines are also slow in Tk text widgets, (...) . Tk uses a b-tree to represent the contents of the widget, but the leaves of the b-tree are lines (everything between two newline characters), so Tk has to do linear searches through lines to find anything.

Comment: Is there another widget that can be appended to, with wrapping? Using a single massive label scrolls more smoothly than the text widget, though trying to load it all at once will eventually crash the program beyond a certain size. If there is nothing else, I might have an idea for a workaround, but I'd need to test it first.

Comment: @Darkstar: you could try using text items on a canvas.

Comment: It is certainly possible that canvas text items would cause less lag, but given that their coordinates need to be specified explicitly, I'm not sure how one would go about wrapping the text automatically. Given that the input will be chosen at random, it will be impossible to know in advance where the line breaks will occur in the text, not to mention what would happen if the user resized the window.